# JS - combining array items together in one item

Tags: javascript

For example I want to collect some tags (lets say paragraph):

```
var tagsCollection = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
var tagsCollectionLength = tagsCollection.length
```

I loop through (iterate):

```
for (var i = 0; i < tagsCollectionLength; i++)
{

//get an array:

var tagsCollectionArray = tagsCollection[i];
}
```

Now what to do to get all array items as ONE item:
so it won't looks like:

> [paragraph1, paragraph2, paragraph3]

but like:

> [paragraph1paragraph2paragraph3]

I did try join. concat. etc. without success probably I'm doing something wrong, any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: So you want 1 paragraph of text instead of multiple paragraphs?

Comment: Do you want to impact the DOM of just the structure of the JS ? `[paragraph1paragraph2paragraph3]` doesn't make any sense, it's like one variable called `paragraph1paragraph2paragraph3`.

Answer (score 5):

you can keep a variable outside the `for`, append the strings inside `for` and when `for` finishes, push it inside an array.
Here's how to do that -

```
var tagsCollection = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
var tagsCollectionLength = tagsCollection.length;
var tags = "", tagsCollectionArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < tagsCollectionLength; i++)
{
   tags = tags + tagsCollection[i];
}
tagsCollectionArray.push(tags);
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me. Your `for` loop could be done with a `.join()`.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have this `html`

```
<div>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>b</p>
  <p>c</p>
  <p>d</p>
  <p>e</p>
</div>
```

Assuming the result you want is an `Array` of all the paragraphs's content (`[paragraph1paragraph2paragraph3]`), then you could do the following:

```
tagsCollection = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

var ar = [];
for(var i = 0; i < tagsCollection.length; i++ ) {
  ar.push(tagsCollection[i].innerText)
}
console.log([ar.join('')]) // => ["abcde"]
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g47bamrh/)

Answer (score 0):

As I have already commented, you can use `Array.join("")`.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/w2dop9ef/).

```js
(function() {
  var data = [];
  var str = [].map.call(document.getElementsByTagName('p'), function(item) {
    return item.innerHTML;
  }).join("");
  data.push(str);
  document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(data) + "</pre>");
})()
```

```html
<p>hello</p>
<p>workd</p>
<p>test</p>
```